# Authentication on node js and express js

Tags: node.js

I have built login page authentication using passport local strategy. Part of the code in **users.js** goes here which is successful..

```
router.post('/login',
      passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
      function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/');
      });
```

But I want to authenticate login using my company credentials through ldap for which I have own module called '**bluepages**' which I have replaced the above block as below.

```
router.post('/login',function(req,res){
    //console.log(req.body);
    res.redirect('/');
    bluepages.authenticate(req.body.username,req.body.password,function(err,verified){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else {
        if(verified)
            return res.redirect('/');
            //console.log('Success');
        else
            return res.redirect('/users/login');
            //console.log('Invalid Credentials');

    }
});
});
```

I get 'success' log when the credentials are correct and 'Invalid Credentials' log when credentials are incorrect. This is working perfect. But my requirement is when res.redirect is not directing to the required view. It remains in login page itself even though credentials are correct. I get the following error which I am not able to solve it. Can you please help me on how to direct the views.

```
_http_outgoing.js:344
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
    ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi you should delete the `res.redirect('/');` after the comment `//console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Hi Marwen, I removed the res.redirect('/'); after the comment //console.log(req.body). Now I am not getting the error which I was getting before. But it is not redirecting to the index view when I am trying to login using correct credentials. The login page has become static after the input of username and password clicking submit button it is not directing to index page. Can you please help me on it.

Comment: hi you should post another question and you should make this question as resolved.